# C++Concurrency in action:Can the Listing7.6(An implementation of pop() using hazard pointers) really detect nodes that can't be reclaimed?

Tags: c++, lock-free

I'm reading the book *C++ Concurrency in Action*. There is an example of using hazard pointer to implement a lock-free stack data structure. I am really puzzled, can the implementation of pop() really detect nodes that can't be reclaimed? The code is as follows:

```
std::shared_ptr<T> pop()
{
  std::atomic<void*>& hp = get_hazard_pointer_for_current_thread();
  node* old_head = head.load();

  do
  {
    node* temp;

    do
    {
      temp = old_head;
      hp.store(old_head);
      old_head = head.load();
    } while(old_head != temp);
  }
  while(old_head &&
    !head.compare_exchange_strong(old_head,old_head->next));

  hp.store(nullptr);
  std::shared_ptr<T> res;

  if(old_head)
  {
    res.swap(old_head->data);

    if(outstanding_hazard_pointers_for(old_head))
    {
      reclaim_later(old_head);
    }
    else
    {
      delete old_head;
    }

    delete_nodes_with_no_hazards();
  }

  return res;
}
```

I have a doubt about this fragment:

```
do
  {
    node* temp;

    do
    {
      temp = old_head;
      hp.store(old_head);
      old_head = head.load();
    } while(old_head != temp);
  }
  while(old_head &&
    !head.compare_exchange_strong(old_head,old_head->next));

  hp.store(nullptr);
```

The purpose of the hazard pointers (hp) is making sure the object that old_head point to is not deleted when other threads may still be using it. It really work when `old_head == hp.load()`. But there is a state here that `old_head != ph.load()`. In this state, the dereference of `old_head` is not safe.
For Example:

- 4 elements in the stack.(`a`->`b`->`c`->`d`)
- `head` is the pointer to the top of the stack.(head->a)
- 3 theads is invoking pop()( Thread `A`,Thread `B`,Thread `C`)

First, thread A is preempted before `head` and `old_head` do compare/exchange

```
....
<================A is preempted here==================>
while(old_head &&
      !head.compare_exchange_strong(old_head,old_head->next));
....
```

the state of Thread A and stack:

```
stack:a->b->c->d (head->a)
Thread A:hp->a old_head->a
```

then, thread B calls the `pop()` and is preempted after `head` and `old_head` do compare/exchange

```
...
while(old_head &&
    !head.compare_exchange_strong(old_head,old_head->next))
<================B is preempted here==================>
hp.store(nullptr);
...
```

the state of Thread A,Thread B and stack:

```
stack:a->b->c->d (head->b)
Thread A: hp->a old_head->a 
Thread B: hp->a old_head->a
```

then, thread A run and is preempted in while loop after `head` and `old_head` do compare/exchange **only once**. Now, hp of thread A have not changed, but old_head points to b.

```
...
while(old_head &&
<================A is preempted here==================>
    !head.compare_exchange_strong(old_head,old_head->next));
...
```

the state of Thread A,Thread B and stack:

```
stack:a->b->c->d (head->b)
Thread A: hp->a old_head->b 
Thread B: hp->a old_head->a
```

then,the thread C calls the `pop()` and runs very fast until `pop()` returns, the element **b** of stack is deleted.

the state of Thread A,Thread B and stack:

```
stack:a->b[deleted] c->d (head->c)
Thread A: hp->a old_head->b[deleted]
Thread B: hp->a old_head->a
```

Now, thread A continue to run.

`head.compare_exchange_strong(old_head,old_head->next)`

program is crashed because of the dereference of old_head (Dangling pointer)

If the implementation is right, where did the above example go wrong?

Comment: After thread C 's pop() returns.Before thread A continue to call compare/exchange for the second time,A:hp and A:old_head have changed to point to c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now, hp of thread A have not changed, but old_head points to b.

Yes, but only temporarily after the `compare_exchange` attempt. Thread B has updated `head` via its `compare_exchange` to `b`, so when thread A attempts to pop `a`, the `compare_exchange` fails and updates `old_head` to point to `b`, *but then thread A starts another iteration of the **outer** loop*. So it again performs the inner loop:

```
    do
    {
      temp = old_head;
      hp.store(old_head);
      old_head = head.load();
    } while(old_head != temp);
```

So when a thread reaches the `while` of the outer loop

```
while(old_head &&
    !head.compare_exchange_strong(old_head,old_head->next));
```

it is guaranteed that `old_head == hp.load()` (you could add an according assertion before these lines).

That way it is guaranteed that each thread has a *safe reference* in `old_head` before it attempts to remove it from the stack.

See [Memory ordering for hazard-pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62240646/memory-ordering-for-hazard-pointers) for more details about how hazard pointers provide the guarantee that either an object is protected via a hazard pointer (i.e., the thread has acquired a safe reference), or the thread that tries to acquire a safe reference to some object sees the updated value (in this case of `head`) and therefore has to perform a retry.